# chart js (version 2) bar chart superimpose one data set onto another

Tags: chart.js

I have a horizontal bar chart with two datasets

I am trying to superimpose the blue bars onto red.so that the intesection can be a start time and the bar can indicate a range.

is there any way to do this?

```
data: {
            labels: ["C#", "ASP.NET MVC", "WebAPI", "SQL", "Entity Framework","NServiceBus / MSMQ", "WCF", "WPF / XAML", "",
                     "HTML / CSS", "JavaScript", "Angular JS v1","",
                     "DI / IoC", "TDD / Unit Testing", "UI Testing (Seleno)", "CI (Teamcity)"],
            datasets: [
                {
                    label:"# years",
                    data: [3, 2, 1, 4, 6, 2, 0.5, 0.25, 0,
                           7, 2, 0.5, 0,
                           2, 2, 0.5, 0.5],
                    backgroundColor: 'red',
                    borderWidth: 0
                },
                {
                    label:"# years",
                    data: [6, 4, 3, 6, 6, 2, 0.5, 0.25, 0,
                           7, 2, 0.5, 0,
                           2, 2, 0.5, 0.5],
                    backgroundColor: 'blue',
                    borderWidth: 0
                }
            ]

        }
```

Comment: got it to work with\

Answer (score 0):

```
options:{
    scales: {
        xAxes: [{ stacked:true}]
            }
        }
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!